# "Se me ha pasado de volada" - ¿Mal dicho?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, méxico, modismos

Una amiga en México siempre me decía que andaba tan ocupada que el tiempo «se le había pasado de volada».

Entiendo el significado implicado pero al realizar una búsqueda en Google (Al *Googlearlo* jeje) no me sale ninguna página con esta frase ni con algo parecido.

Sé que existe el «el tiempo se me ha pasado volando» lo cual me parece tener todo sentido pero quería saber si esta frase si existe o si es nada más otro mexicanismo, o jugada de la lengua entre amigos.

Comment: aqui en peru tambien se utiliza ese termino sinonimo que ha pasado algo muy rapido .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"De volada" significa "muy rápido" si ella dice que el tiempo se le fue de volada significa que se le fue muy rápido.

```
¡Vete por las tortillas de volada! [Vete por las tortillas, rápido]
```

Es bastante normal en México. Se puede utilizar en todos los contextos, formales e informales, a menos claro que el asunto requiera extrema formalidad, pero no debería haber ningún problema.

Comment: Gracias :) sabia que queria decir pero no si era común decirlo así :)

Comment: En España habríamos dicho *volando*, en lugar de *de volada*. Tal vez en otros países de habla hispana se usen también estas mismas expresiones u otras parecidas.

Comment: @Gorpik Lo mismo en Argentina: _volando_. Jamás escuché _de volada_.

Answer (score 2):

Como comentario adicional "de volada" también lo usamos en México como sinónimo de mujer que anda coqueteando

"Adriana anda de volada con el hijo de don Toño"

Answer (score 0):

En Guatemala se utiliza  en su lugar volando, confirmando el comentario de Gorpik.
Pero en un ambiente informal es bastante comun utilizar oraciones como los ejemplos abajo.

> Ayudame a entrar la ropa. **Pero picale!**
>
> Ayudame a entrar la ropa. **Pero para ayer!**
>
> Ayudame a entrar la ropa. **Pero saca chispa!**

Answer (score -1):

De voladas se usa como sinónimo de: mas o menos, algo, un poco. Denota cierta cantidad pero no en su totalidad.

Comment: No sé si esa expresión se usa en algún lugar (yo no la conocía). Pero, desde luego, en el ejemplo de la pregunta no significa eso.